# A question from One Dimensional Dynamics book by De-Melo and van-Strien

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

In [One Dimensional Dynamics](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/sebastian_van_strien/demelo-strien.pdf), on page 27 I don't understand how does $(1.7)$ follow; anyone care to explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

I am adding some information from the text below:
We are considering a rotation $R=R_{\alpha} = x+\alpha \mod 1$.Let $\theta_0=\alpha$, which is the length of the interval: $(c,R(c^-))$ , and let $\theta_n$ be the length of $J_n ' = (c, R^{q_n}(c^+))$ for $n\ge 1$, since $R^n(x) = x +n\alpha \mod 1$ we have $\theta_n = \inf_{p\in \mathbb{Z}} (q_n \alpha - p)$.
$q_n$ is defined inductively as $q_0=1 , q_1 = a_1 , q_{n+1}= q_{n-1}+a_{n+1}q_n \ for \ n\ge 1$.
$\phi_1$ is defined as the first return map, $\mathcal{R}(f)$ if the interval $J'$ is to the right of $J''$ and it's $f$ if $J'$ is to the left of $J''$.

$a(f)$ is defined as the smallest integer s.t $J'$ and $f^{a(f)+1}(J')$ have a common point, $J(f)$ is defined as the closure of $f^{a(f)+1}(J')\cup J'$.

$a_1$ is defined as $a(f)+1$ if $J'$ is to the right of $J''$ and to $1$ when $J'$ is left of $J''$.
Now inductively, we define: $J_n = J(\phi_{n-1})$, $\phi_n = \mathcal{R}(\phi_{n-1})$ and $a_n = a(\phi_{n-1})$.

$J'$ and $J''$ are the interiors of components of $J\setminus \{ c(f) \}$.
$f$ and $\phi_1$ are homoeomorphisms of intervals on the circle $S^1$,$c(f)$ is a point of discontinuity of $f$ in the interval $J$.

To define the first return map $\mathcal{R}(f)$: if $I \subset J$ is a closed interval such that the forward $f$-orbit through any point of $I$ intersects $I$, we define the first return map $\mathcal{R}(f):I\to I$ of $f$ to $I$ as $\mathcal{R} (f) = f^k(x)$ where $k=k(x) =\min \{ i>0: f^i(x) \in I \}$.

What I don't understand is how do the following identities follow:
$$(1.7) 1=a_1\theta_0 + \theta_1 ,  \ \ \theta_{n-1} = a_{n+1}\theta_n+\theta_{n+1} \ for \ n\ge 1$$
on page 27.

P.S
I asked this question in MSE but it got deleted, I don't understand why, since I have described all the necessary background before equation $(1.7)$; and I didn't get any notice of why it got deleted.

Comment: Question with low views, no upvotes and no activity get automatically deleted after a while.

Comment: It would be good to provide a link to the MSE question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson here's the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475052/question-from-one-dimensional-dynamics-of-van-strein-and-de-melo

Comment: What $\Phi_{n}$ means?
Anyhow, the first equality follows by definitions. The second one seems (with those horrible notions) to follow from the continued fraction expansion. In any case, this is not research related question.